# Adding fake field value to database query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy several websites and merge their content into a single website, similar to Wikipedia. I'll need to query many different tables, which is going to get sloppy. So I want to give each table unique values for $Site and $Section.

One strategy is to create a simple script that queries a single field from each table, like this...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT GS.URL
 FROM gs_world GS
 WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT G.URL FROM gw2_pol G
 WHERE G.URL = :MyURL");
$stm->execute(array(
'MyURL'=>$MyURL,
));
```

I then need to somehow modify the query so it gives each table unique values for $Site and $Section, like this:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT GS.URL, $Site AS 'GS', $Section AS 'World'
 FROM gs_world GS
 WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT G.URL FROM gw2_pol G, $Site AS 'GW', $Section AS 'World'
 WHERE G.URL = :MyURL");
$stm->execute(array(
'MyURL'=>$MyURL,
));
```

Instead of creating a huge, hopelessly complex query to extract other values, I can then make customized queries, placed inside a switch...

```
switch($MySection)
{
 case 'World':
 [query]
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

Anyway, can anyone tell me how to give each table a default value for $Site and $Section, even though neither table has a field with such values?

---

Got it. This is what I think the complete solution will look like...

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT GS.URL, 'GS' as Site, 'World' as Section
 FROM gs_world GS
 WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT G.URL, 'GW' as Site, 'World' as Section
 FROM gw2_pol G
 WHERE G.URL = :MyURL");
$stm->execute(array(
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Site = $row['Site'];
 $Section = $row['Section'];
}
```

I can now use the above values to make more detailed queries...

```
switch($Section)
{
 case 'World':
  // INNER SWITCH
  switch($Site)
  {
   case 'GS':
   // [query the table gs_world]
   break;
   default:
   // [detailed query of gw2_pol]
   break;
  }
  // END INNER SWITCH
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

Comment: while you can definitely put static values in a SQL statement, I've never seen and don't believe you can use bind parameters in the SELECT portion of the query

Comment: @ScottSosna: bind variables *can* be expressions (or parts of expressions) in the SELECT list of a query.

Comment: We usually use the term "**discriminator column**" as the name for the fake field added to the SELECT list of each query in the UNION ALL query. That's the column that lets us determine which SELECT return each row in the resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you want is just a slight modification of what you have:

```
SELECT GS.URL, 'GS' as Site, 'World' as Section
FROM gs_world GS
WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT G.URL FROM gw2_pol G, 'GW' as Site, 'World' as Section
FROM . . .
WHERE G.URL = :MyURL
```

I'm not sure what the variables `$site` and `$section` are supposed to be.

Comment: there's a couple issues with the statement. The literals in the second SELECT appear after the FROM clause; those need to be moved *before* the `FROM`.  (It looks like you added a second FROM clause as a partial fix.  Also with PDO, we can't reference the same bind placeholder more than once in a statement... it can't be reused, each bind parameter has to have a unique name. (That used to be the case at least; it's possible this is fixed in a later release.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to supply the values to be returned, either as literals, or as bind variables.

In a `UNION ALL` (or `UNION`) query, the column names are defined by the first query. So you can't use the name of the column in the resultset as a discriminator. To tell which query returned a row, you will need distinct values in each query.

Also, there's issues with PDO reusing a bind parameter in the statement more than once. That doesn't work. (At least, it didn't used to work... it's possible the behavior has changed in a later release of PDO.)

```
$sql = "SELECT GS.URL
             , :gs_site     AS `site`
             , :gs_section  AS `section`
          FROM gs_world GS
         WHERE GS.URL = :gs_MyURL
         UNION ALL
        SELECT G.URL
             , :g_site      AS `site`
             , :g_section   AS `section`
          FROM gw2_pol G
         WHERE G.URL = :g_MyURL ";

$params = array(
    ':gs_MyURL'   => $MyURL,
    ':gs_site'    => 'GS',
    ':gs_section' => 'World',
    ':g_MyURL'    => $MyURL,
    ':g_site'     => 'GW',
    ':g_section'  => 'World'
    );

$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

---

If you don't want to pass the discriminator values as bind values, you can just  hardcode literals into the SQL text, in place of the bind placeholders e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT GS.URL
             , 'GS'         AS `site`
             , 'World'      AS `section`
          FROM gs_world GS
         ... ";
```

Comment: I modified my original post, appending my revised code using the first suggestion. It appears to be working so far, but I'll check out your solution, too.

Comment: The query in the original question has some problems... the FROM clause in the second SELECT appears before expressions that should be in the SELECT list. And reuse of the same bind placeholder.

Comment: Good catch; I fixed it. Actually, I don't think I need to use $MyURL in this query; I just need it in the more detailed queries. On the other hand, I think using it would make this query a little faster.